# How can I make a column display certain text based on another columns data in an IBM Cognos report?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

For example, the structure of the report is like this:

```css
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-c6of{background-color:#ffffff;border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-c6of">Identifier</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Codes</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Mixed Codes?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">123456789</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">111</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky" rowspan="3">YES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">987654321</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">222</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">NO</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to hide the "Codes" column completely and only have Cognos display a Yes or No in the "Mixed Codes?" column if there are mixed codes attached to the identifier.
So far I have not been able to get this to work with an IF statement in the data expression as the data is pulled on a per-row basis.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "mixed codes" mean?  Are you just saying identifier 123456789 has more than one code?

Comment: It's a data item attached to the identifier, like Identifier | Name | Address | City/State | Codes

Each identifier can have multiple codes attached to it or none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [Codes] from the query.
[Mixed Codes?] should be defined as

```
CASE
    WHEN count(distinct [namespace].[query subject].[Codes]) > 1 THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
END
```

Comment: That partially works, but it is creating the yes's and no's on a per-row basis. What I'm going for is more of a single row "Yes, this identifier has multiple codes" or a "No, this identifier has only one or none codes" kind of thing. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Actually never mind, I missed a keyword, it works perfectly! thank you!

Comment: If its just a display you are looking for and no further manipulation is required, aka no count or filters,  you could also keep this out of the SQL by doing it as Report Expression on the data items [Codes] display.